# Spyder is no longer queueing commands

Tags: python, spyder

I run python in Spyder, and I execute lines or cells in a file using alt-enter or shift-enter. 
Currently, according to the "About Spyder" menu option, I am using Spyder 4.0.1.

Recently, my Spyder was (apparently) upgraded -- I don't know what version I was running before, and I didn't upgrade it explicitly, it must have happened as part of some other general upgrade.  Perhaps I deserve grief for "accidentally" upgrading my Spyder, but that's another matter...

The problem is, the behavior has changed.  Previously, I could quickly execute a number of lines consecutively by hitting alt-enter repeatedly (or a number of cells with shift-enter).  Now, I have to wait for each command to finish executing before executing the next one.  In other words, if I hit alt-enter while the previous command is still running, instead of queueing the command for subsequent execution, it just ignores it.

I would like to get the old behavior back.  Does anyone know if there is a setting somewhere that does this?  I wasn't able to find one.

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.spyder-ide.org/internalconsole.html

Comment: I ran into this last week after updating, it seems the issue is identified and a fix is being discussed by the developers: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/9725

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) That functionality was removed a couple of years ago (I don't remember in what exact version. sorry). However, we're planning to read it for Spyder 5, to be released in a year or so.